# Using custom RoleClaimType on OAuthBearer middleware

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, claims-based-identity

The OAuth server issues role claims using different claim type from `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role`:

```cs
var adminRole = new Claim("CustomRole", "Admin");
context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(adminRole);
```

How can I tell the `OAuthBearerAuthentication` middleware to use my custom role claim type so it gets the `Authorize` attribute to work:

```cs
//Startup
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions ...

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IHttpActionResult SecureAction()
```

Comment: Why not use `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role` instead of "CustomRole"?

Comment: Because `Authorization Server` issues different ClaimTypes for each `Resource Server`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `OnValidateIdentity` function of `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider`, we can rebind `ClaimsIdentity` with appropriate `RolaClaimType` and `NameClaimType`:

```cs
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = context =>
        {
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                context.Ticket.Identity.Claims,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CustomClaimTypes.Name,
                CustomClaimTypes.Role);

            context.Validated(claimsIdentity);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your `Identity` is set to an instance of [`System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity?view=netcore-2.1):

- The [`ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.roleclaimtype?view=netcore-2.1) property is used to specify the claim that represents the *role*, and it's used when evaluating this identity for the `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole(String)` method.

You can easily clone your original identity from the original one (passing the original claims) and specifying a different `roleType` name using the constructor:

[`ClaimsIdentity(IIdentity, IEnumerable<Claim>, String, String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.-ctor?view=netcore-2.1#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsIdentity__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Security_Claims_Claim__System_String_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: Can you provide the correct place of doing this? I did it in `OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.Provider.OnValidateIdentity` of `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` middleware.